# How to compare YTD and PYYTD if dates are different in both years

Tags: powerbi, dax, analytics, measure

if in year 2023 Oct have 1 oct to 27 oct data
and in 2022 oct have 1 oct to 28 oct data
then how to compare ytd or pyytd
in my data display in 2022 only till 27 oct data comparison
I want also 28 oct data in my pyytd

Please provide me power bi DAX

Comment: What calculation are using for `PYYTD`?